# Django does not throw ValidationError when required fields are not present

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am currently testing my django model using pytest (and pytest-django), but I can not write a failing test case in which a required field is missing.

My `Person`-model requires solely a `name` and a `company`. The other fields are nullable and therefore optional.

`models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.name}"
                + (f", {self.position}" if self.position is not None else "")
                + f"({self.company})"
                + (f" born {self.date_of_birth}" if self.date_of_birth is not None else "")
                )
```

`test.py`

```py
from .models import Person
import pytest
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


# Create your tests here.
def test_minimal_person():
    """Test if a minimal person can be created"""
    valid_person = Person(name="Max Mustermann", company="ACME")
    valid_person.save()

    assert len(Person.objects.get_queryset()) == 1


def test_insufficient_params():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        invalid_person = Person()
        invalid_person.save()


def test_missing_company():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        invalid_person = Person(name="Max")
        invalid_person.save()


def test_missing_name():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        invalid_person = Person(company="ACME")
        invalid_person.save()


def test_invalid_date_format():
    """Test if an invalid date format throws a ValidationError"""
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        invalid_person = Person(name="Max", company="ACME", date_of_birth="not-a-date")
        invalid_person.save()
```

The test `test_invalid_date_format` and `test_minimal_person` succeed, but the other ones do not throw an (expected) error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save()` method doesn't do any validation for your fields, because they can go in the database when empty. See [What happens when you save?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save) The reason an invalid date throws a `ValidationError` is because it's not a date. However, an empty string is still a string and can be stored in the database as such. To force validation, call the `full_clean()` method of the model object.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! Interesting that I did not find anything about `full_clean()` in the [tutorial about testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial05/).

Comment: Generally you're not going to want to test direct data entry, but rather forms, which automatically validate and so don't need `full_clean()`.

Comment: I do use forms as well, but I wanted to test this part as well. Next on the list would be to test the forms as well.